# Given $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) $ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)$, evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x^3-x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $ \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = A$ and $ \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) = B  $

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x^3-x)$

I tried working with polynomials and e-d definitions, but couldn't get anywhere

Answer (score 2):

For $x \in (0,1)$ we have $x^3-x<0$. Prove this !

hence $x^3-x \to 0^-$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Consequence: $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x^3-x)=B$

Answer (score 1):

Note that As $x \to 0^+$, $x(x+1)(x-1) \to 0^-$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x^3 - x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = B$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Set $y:= x^3 -x.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} (x^3-x) = $

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} y.$

$\lim_{ y \rightarrow 0^-} f(y) = B.$

$  \ $

Proof of

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}(x^3-x) =$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} y.$

$ \ $

Let $x\in (0,\epsilon)$, $\epsilon >0.$

$y = x^3-x = (x-1)(x+1)x.$

Choose $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$, then  $y <0 $, and

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \rightarrow 0^+ =$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n \rightarrow 0^-,$

where $y_n = (x_n^3 - x_n).$